# What is this object on the tail of an F-16?

Tags: feature-identification, f-16

[image: F-16]
Source: [skytamer.com](https://www.skytamer.com/5.8.htm)

What is the object on the tail of this F-16 (next to the serial number)?

Comment: Must be where the jump starter cable goes ;-)

Comment: Chemtrail Output Valve (portside)

Comment: @Richard: close. That's the starboard side of the ship.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [image]
>   Source: [primeportal.net](http://www.primeportal.net/hangar/don_busack/f-16c-1/); cropped

That's the cooling-air outlet that is aft of the cooling inlet. In between is a power amplifier for the [radar-warning system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_warning_receiver).

> [image]
>   Source: [amazon.co.uk](https://www.amazon.co.uk/General-Dynamics-Fighting-Falcon-Manual/dp/0857333984) (one of the product images); cropped
>
> 118: Cooling-air ram air intake
>   124: Radar-warning system power amplifier

Related: [What is the device at the tail of the F-16 Block 60?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/69878/14897)

Comment: That is a very non-aerodynamic looking inlet duct! Had the design team not heard of NACA? Obviously, it's suitable to purpose, but... wow...